# SE general should have a reputation metric which you can gain from any site

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-exchange

As a SE poster, I can only suggest things. 
SE should have reputation metric to measure that you are entity of general good character- not spammer, not marketer, not flamer, general awareness of the  SE sites, general trustworthiness etc. 
As against individual sites measuring your particular reputation as being good at understanding their site, significant contributor in many different ways, good at the fields covered by the site.

It would reduce the annoyance at the limited cover over of reputation- if need be create a new SE site solely for handling general reputation. If you gain high in general reputation than you'd be either be in line to be a limited moderator or simply advanced access to advanced privileges in all site. Naturally need new badges for general reputation.

Comment: So you're saying this 'general' reputation would be able to grant me high-rep user privs on *any* site?

Comment: Not necessarily- just you'd need less local reputation- by the way you'd gain it from posting at any site in a different way.

Answer (score 11):

The association bonus already gives you basic privileges, such as commenting and voting up.

You need to first get familiar with a certain site before being able to gain more advanced privileges. Some sites may have different rules and guidelines than others. You need to "prove yourself" and show that you understand the site's topic and rules.

For example, if I was a very good cook, and got 30000 reputation on the cooking site, would you trust me to moderate Stack Overflow? Or if I was an avid user on the bycicles site, would you let me moderate Photography?

Comment: Yes- to a certain degree- a good person is a good person. If you are good trustworthy person- you can spot spam or flaming or simple spelling/grammatical errors no matter which site you are on. The 30000 reputation on the cooking site wouldn't auto carry over to general reputation so you could just have say 100 on the general- i.e. a reasonable person who isn't trustworthy enough to not post inflammatory  post/comments.  You are missing the semi-separateness of general reputation- you are good in a different way. But I appreciate your generally reasonable argument.

Comment: @user2617804 I think you need to be more specific about what privileges you are looking for on other sites that you can't get from the association bonus.  In the end, earn 200 rep on any site and you are free to comment everywhere (as well as anything else 100 rep will get you).  What else do you want/need?